# Table in Beamer presentation

Tags: tables, beamer

I want to create the following table in the beamer presentation but the command didn't work. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Namely, should I use other packages or what?

```
\begin{table}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
\tempdima=\dimexpr \textwidth/7 - 2\tabcolsep\relax
\small
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc} \hline\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Sample window} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Probability cutoff value} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Crises correctly called (\%)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Missed crises (\%)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{False alarm (\%)} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{TME}  \\ 

\midrule 

&&& \multicolumn{3}{p{\tempdima}}{In-sample}\\\addlinespace[0.75ex]

1970-2000 & 0.1  &  75.32 & 67.24 & 24.68 & 32.76 & 57.43 \\

1970-2003 & 0.1  & 74.07 & 71.05 & 25.93 & 28.95 & 54.87 \\

1970-2006 & 0.09 & 76.19 & 68.81 & 23.81 & 31.19 & 54.99 \\

1970-2009 & 0.09 & 77.89 & 66.86 & 22.11 & 33.14 & 55.25\\

1970-2012 & 0.09 & 73.68 & 70.85 & 26.32 & 29.15 & 55.46 \\

1970-2015 & 0.09 & 77.14 & 70.45 & 22.86 & 29.55 & 52.40 \\ 

\midrule 

&&&  \multicolumn{3}{p{\tempdima}}{Out-of-sample}   \\

2001-2003 & 0.1 & 75 & 80.95 & 25.00 & 19.05 & 44.04 \\


2004-2006 & 0.1 & 33.33 & 91.86 & 66.67 & 8.14 & 74.80 \\

2007-2009 & 0.09 & 54.55 & 82.89 & 45.45 & 17.11 & 62.55 \\

2010-2012 & 0.09 & 0 & 72.41 & 0 &  27.59 & 27.59 \\

2013-2015 & 0.09 & 80.00 & 74.36 & 20.00 & 25.64 & 45.64 \\

2016-2018 & 0.09 & 66.67 & 87.21 & 33.33 & 12.79 & 46.12 \\  \hline

\end{tabular}}
\caption{3-year ahead in- and out-of-sample prediction}
\label{table: prediction}
\end{table}
```

I got the following warning:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You

- not define length `\tempdima˙,
- forgot on `\begin{table}`
- forgot put table in `frame`
- forgot to increase width of the `multicolumn` cell or use `c` column tape instead of `p{\tempdima}`

Correcting aforementioned, your table is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newlength\tempdima

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
\setlength\tempdima{\dimexpr \textwidth/7 - 2\tabcolsep\relax}
\small
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc} \hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Sample window} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Probability cutoff value} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Missed crises (\%)} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{False alarm (\%)} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{TME}  \\
    \midrule
&&& \multicolumn{3}{c}{In-sample}   \\
 \addlinespace
1970-2000 & 0.1  &  75.32 & 67.24 & 24.68 & 32.76 & 57.43 \\
1970-2003 & 0.1  & 74.07 & 71.05 & 25.93 & 28.95 & 54.87 \\
1970-2006 & 0.09 & 76.19 & 68.81 & 23.81 & 31.19 & 54.99 \\
1970-2009 & 0.09 & 77.89 & 66.86 & 22.11 & 33.14 & 55.25\\
1970-2012 & 0.09 & 73.68 & 70.85 & 26.32 & 29.15 & 55.46 \\
1970-2015 & 0.09 & 77.14 & 70.45 & 22.86 & 29.55 & 52.40 \\

\midrule
&&&  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Out-of-sample}   \\
2001-2003 & 0.1 & 75 & 80.95 & 25.00 & 19.05 & 44.04 \\
2004-2006 & 0.1 & 33.33 & 91.86 & 66.67 & 8.14 & 74.80 \\
2007-2009 & 0.09 & 54.55 & 82.89 & 45.45 & 17.11 & 62.55 \\
2010-2012 & 0.09 & 0 & 72.41 & 0 &  27.59 & 27.59 \\
2013-2015 & 0.09 & 80.00 & 74.36 & 20.00 & 25.64 & 45.64 \\
2016-2018 & 0.09 & 66.67 & 87.21 & 33.33 & 12.79 & 46.12 \\  \hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{3-year ahead in- and out-of-sample prediction}
\label{table: prediction}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
You may consider to use `tabularx` table and `S` columns type defined in the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
 \addlinespace
1970-2000 & 0.1  &  75.32 & 67.24 & 24.68 & 32.76 & 57.43 \\
1970-2003 & 0.1  & 74.07 & 71.05 & 25.93 & 28.95 & 54.87 \\
1970-2006 & 0.09 & 76.19 & 68.81 & 23.81 & 31.19 & 54.99 \\
1970-2009 & 0.09 & 77.89 & 66.86 & 22.11 & 33.14 & 55.25\\
1970-2012 & 0.09 & 73.68 & 70.85 & 26.32 & 29.15 & 55.46 \\
1970-2015 & 0.09 & 77.14 & 70.45 & 22.86 & 29.55 & 52.40 \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
&  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Out-of-sample}   \\
2001-2003 & 0.1 & 75 & 80.95 & 25.00 & 19.05 & 44.04 \\
2004-2006 & 0.1 & 33.33 & 91.86 & 66.67 & 8.14 & 74.80 \\
2007-2009 & 0.09 & 54.55 & 82.89 & 45.45 & 17.11 & 62.55 \\
2010-2012 & 0.09 & 0 & 72.41 & 0 &  27.59 & 27.59 \\
2013-2015 & 0.09 & 80.00 & 74.36 & 20.00 & 25.64 & 45.64 \\
2016-2018 & 0.09 & 66.67 & 87.21 & 33.33 & 12.79 & 46.12 \\  
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{3-year ahead in- and out-of-sample prediction}
\label{table: prediction}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: The command works very well. I h just want to let the table continue on the next page since this is bigger than the table I posted here. Can you help me with the command?

Comment: @Arbnor, multi page table in beamer?In presentation are tables boring ... Regard this, please ask new question. However, since my answer solve your problem, it will be nice from you, if you would up-vote and answer and even accept it (by clicking on up-pen and check mark at top left side of answer. As I see, so far you not do this at any received answer :-(